# can i get httpOnly cookie work with vue-resource?

Tags: http, cookies, vue.js, vue-resource

work on a full spa with `vue`, `vue-router`, `vue-resource`, etc.
sending request with vue-resource and server will return a response with a set-cookie header, but it is a httpOnly cookie, how could I make this cookie also work with the `vue-resource` request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks, HTTP-only cookies aren't accessible via JavaScript through the Document.cookie property, the XMLHttpRequest and Request APIs.

You may refer to here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies